# FileNotFoundError while accessing the file server(python) side which is uploaded from clientside(angular)

Tags: python, angular, file-upload

FileNotFoundError while accessing the file server(python) side which is uploaded from clientside(angular). I get file path as ''C:\fakepath\filename.txt'.
I am trying to send file and form data in one request to server side. so iam appending file and data to formData.
So I want to get read/write/.. text file which uploaded from client (angular) in python . Please suggest.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Data', JSON.stringify(this.Data));
formData.append('file', this.Form.controls['FILE'].value);

this.httpClient.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/form", formData)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      alert("Post to Form route is Success!");
});
```

```py
@app.route('/form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def form():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data =  request.form
        Data =  data['Data']
        file = data['file']
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            print(f.readlines())
```

Comment: Welcome Sail :)

Does your python server get the right file path? If so your question is basically how to read that. If not your question is how to send / receive that file path. Pls narrow your problem down as much as possible

Comment: Yes Raphael. i get file path as ''C:\\fakepath\\file.txt'' and I use request.form to get it. But I get 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:' when i am trying to access it. I get ImmutableMultiDict([]) from angular while to flask for request.files

Comment: As this error occurs on server site we can skip the angular site for the moment. Pls check a) The file exists for sure ;) and b) you don't get confused with those backslash escapes. Check if it works with the hard coded path `open('C:\\fakepath\\file.txt' , 'rb')`

Comment: Solved: Angular reactive form takes file input as <input type="file" id="avatar" (change)="onFileChange($event)">                                                                            ```angular```   onFileChange(event) {
    if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.form.get('avatar').setValue(file);
    }
  }